# UI automated testing PHP application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, testing

I have a PHP web application which uses jQuery for client side interactions and DOM manipulation.

What type of automated testing can I run on my code to make sure it is working as expected on mobile devices.

E.g. On iPhone I want to check a button click shows a hidden field.

On Android my latest deployment is working ok for a click but iPhone not.

I would like to build in some simple automation tests during each build (builds via Codeship).